# Is there a way to make apache server interpret files with .png extension as .php?

Tags: php, apache, png

Is there a way to make apache server interpret files with .png extension as .php? Can it be done with .htaccess?

my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .png
```

my image.png

```
<?php

showImage();

function showImage()
{
    $image = @imagecreatefrompng("../aimage.png");
    header("Content-type: image/png;"); 
    imagepng($image );
    imagedestroy($image);
}

?>
```

and its not working.

When i go to www.example.com/image.png
i get 'The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors',
when that image.png is image.php it displays the image like it should.

Any ideas?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: What server software? Apache? IIS?

Comment: Elaborate? we need info.

Comment: Try without the @ . Try without the space in imagepng. Make sure there is no blanks around the <?php ..?> . Try to let it give a echo 'test'; before inserting the image stuff. Make sure the .htaccess has sufficient rights set.

Answer (score 6):

You say you have Apache? Add this to your [`.htaccess`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) or [`httpd.conf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Httpd.conf) file.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .foo
```

Comment: Hm, when I open the .foo file its not working like php but instead I'm offered to download it.

Comment: Should I add 'RewriteEngine on' or something? I didn't have any .htaccess file before in this directory.

Comment: restart apache server if you did it in httpd.conf

Comment: I have putted it in .htaccess